# Running specific python interpreters form command line

Tags: python, windows, cmd, path

When I open CMD (on windows 10) and enter `python` it initializes python 3.6.0

```
C:\>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Now I recently also installed 2.7.6 the interpreter. How can I call both version of Python from CMD?

*desired outcome*

```
C:\>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> ^Z
C:\>python2.6
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: You can copy or symlink python.exe to python2.7.exe, and then add the Python 2.7 installation directory to the `PATH` environment variable. Or just use the py.exe launcher, e.g. `py -2` or `py -2.7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Python launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows):

- Python 2.7 interptreter:

  > C:\> py -2.7
- Python 3.6 interpreter:

  > C:\> py -3.6

You also can run a script with a specific interpreter:

> C:\> py -2.7 myScript.py

Answer (score 0):

If its windows machine, to open a specific version of python you can use py from the command line.

example:
py2.7 #for version 2.7

and

py3.6 #for version 3.6

if its a Linux machine you can use the following commands in the command line python

python2.7 #opens version 2.7

and

python3.6 #opens version 3.6

Comment: It's `py -2.7` and `py -3.6`. `py` on its own used to default to the latest version of Python 2 installed. Starting with 3.6, it uses the latest version of Python 3. An active virtual environment overrides this default. You can also override it via the `PY_PYTHON` environment variable.